# Twilio - How to dial third party number and add him to conference?

Tags: php, api, twilio, phone-call, twilio-twiml

I am facing a small problem while using Twilio conference.

My API gets incoming call and puts caller to new and empty conference room:

```
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Conference waitUrl="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient">Conf 1</Conference>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

So I got caller waiting in an empty conference room and listening music.
I want to dial some other number and to add it to this confrence room.
That number is non-twilio.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the Twilio REST API to make an outbound call, and direct that call into your conference room. In PHP this can be done like this:

(This is from the [twilio-php helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install))

```
require('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php');

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
  'some-twilio-number', // From a valid Twilio number
  'other-number-to-call', // Number to call
  'http://example.com/some_twiml'
);
```

The URL you use here should serve TwiML that puts the caller into the same room as your original call (exactly as you have in your question). In effect, one person called you, then you called the other person and put them into the same room.

(In the interests of full disclosure, I worked for Twilio.)

Comment: Excellent idea! And is there a way to record the conference talk?

Comment: There is a [Twilio FAQ](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/is-there-a-more-flexible-way-to-record-conference-calls) on this. I think the <Dial record="true"> approach would work for you? Don't forget to set an action="" URL so Twilio knows where to send your recording. You also probably only want to have the record on one of the calls, or you'll be recording it twice!

Comment: From android side can i do same using follwoing code? 
resp.dial(callerId=from_value).client('SOME NUMBER').conference('room name');
Please guide me

Comment: @KhizarHayat did you find a solution on that conference call
I have the same problem

Comment: @Martin no i am not calling thirdparty from mobile end , my server guy dialing third party .

Comment: @KhizarHayat I did lot's of search on that problem 
and every twilio question you where there 
can I tack 5 min of you time?

Comment: I am trying to handle that with the server

Comment: What is the exactly issue if you are trying to handle that with the server ? @Martin

Comment: can you please ping me here @MatinShoaib at twitter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885628/adding-multiple-people-to-a-conference-call-from-caller-twilio/43950460#43950460
@KhizarHayat check this link
I found a solution for that

Comment: what will be the twiml @xmjw

Comment: You made my day! I was looking for a way to make an outgoing conference call to an external number and seemed like no one knew, including Twilio support. This is a perfect answer. I would add a TWIML for an argument for create call: twiml: "<Response><Dial><Conference>conference_id</Conference></Dial></Response>"