# Outgoing Dial Into Conference From Customer's Number

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to have all my incoming calls automatically go to conference. This part can be achieved using:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Conference>Room <?php echo($_REQUEST['From']);?></Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

This way, each caller goes into their own separate conference room. The part I can't figure out how to do is the outbound call from that point. I need to make a SIP call to my PBX using the customer's caller id so an agent can answer it. When they answer, they should be sent to the same conference room.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16170388/twilio-how-to-dial-third-party-number-and-add-him-to-conference) for making outbound calls into a conference. However, I want the outbound call to the agent to use the caller id of the customer. This way, the agent can see the customer's phone number.

The main reason I want to use a conference and not a direct dial is because I want to make it possible for supervisors to call into an active call without interrupting the call between the agent and customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I believe that when making SIP calls, the From parameter will take any alphanumeric string so you can just provide the customers caller ID as the From value:

```
$call = $client->account->calls->create($_REQUEST['From'], "sip:agent@example.com", "http://www.example.com/conference.xml", array());
echo $call->sid;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is this expected behavior or something that could change later? The documentation says I can only use verified caller ids.

Comment: This is expected behavior.